# Magento2: How to make ajax based newsletter subscription & move success message just below subscription field

Tags: magento2, newsletter, success-message, subscription

I have subscription block before my footer links and after successful subscription the message appears on the top of main part, but I want to show it below subscription input.Of course there should be also different loading, cause now all page refreshes after success input.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below Extension:

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-ajax-newsletter-subscription/tree/master

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial!

Comment: Maybe you know how to prevent scrolling to the top, after the user input incorrect text in the email field?

Comment: Using changes on js file you can fulfill your requirement otherwise move the class using move tag on xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the below code process to make it ajax based and can make required changes as per your requirements.

**Create di.xml at [Namespace][ModuleName]\etc folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction">
        <plugin name="Custom_Newsletter_Subscriber_Action" type="[Namespace]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Plugin\Subscriber\NewAction" sortOrder="11" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Create NewAction.php at [Namespace][ModuleName]\Controller\Plugin\Subscriber folder:**

```
<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Plugin\Subscriber;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface as CustomerAccountManagement;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress as EmailValidator;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Class NewAction
 */
class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{
    /**
     * @var EmailValidator
     */
    private $emailValidator;

    /**
     * @var SubscriptionManagerInterface
     */
    private $subscriptionManager;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var CustomerAccountManagement
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
     * @param CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        SubscriptionManagerInterface $subscriptionManager,
        EmailValidator $emailValidator = null,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository = null
    ) {
        $this->subscriptionManager = $subscriptionManager;
        $this->emailValidator = $emailValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(EmailValidator::class);
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $customerSession,
            $storeManager,
            $customerUrl,
            $customerAccountManagement,
            $subscriptionManager,
            $emailValidator,
            $customerRepository
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve available Order fields list
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundExecute($subject, $procede)
    {
        $response = [];
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

            try {
                $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                $status = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $response = [
                        'status' => 'OK',
                        'msg' => 'The confirmation request has been sent.',
                    ];
                } else {
                    $response = [
                        'status' => 'OK',
                        'msg' => 'Thank you for your subscription.',
                    ];
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $response = [
                    'status' => 'ERROR',
                    'msg' => __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage()),
                ];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $response = [
                    'status' => 'ERROR',
                    'msg' => __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'),
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData($response);
    }
}
```

**Create subscribe.phtml file into your theme:**
eg: app\design\frontend\Theme\child\Magento_Newsletter\templates\subscribe.phtml

```
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title"><strong>Newsletter </strong></div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe" novalidate action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}' id="newsletter-validate-detail">

            <div class="field newsletter">
                <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter your email address') ?>" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe sad') ?>" type="submit">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe') ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="scg-msg">
                <div class="messages">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        var form = $('#newsletter-validate-detail');
        form.submit(function(e) {
            if (form.validation('isValid')) {
                var email = $("#newsletter-validate-detail #newsletter").val();
                var url = form.attr('action');
                var loadingMessage = $('#loading-message');

                if (loadingMessage.length == 0) {
                    form.find('.input-group').append('<div id="loading-message" style="display:none;padding-top:10px;color: red;font-size: 13px;">&nbsp;</div>');
                    var loadingMessage = $('#loading-message');
                }

                e.preventDefault();
                try {
                    loadingMessage.html('Submitting...').show();
                    $('.scg-msg > messages').html();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            email: email
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data.status != "ERROR") {
                                $("#newsletter-validate-detail #newsletter").val('');
                                $('#newsletter-validate-detail .scg-msg > .messages').html('<div class="message-success success message" ><div >' +
                                    data.msg + '</div></div>');
                            } else {
                                $('#newsletter-validate-detail .scg-msg > .messages').html('<div class="message-error error message" >' +
                                    '<div>' + data.msg + '</div></div>');
                            }
                            loadingMessage.html(data.msg);
                        },
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    loadingMessage.html(e.message);
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Just follow the mentioned steps & your newsletter will work as per your requirements.

Comment: Maybe you know how to prevent scrolling to the top, after the user input incorrect text in the email field?